# Recursive method returns only null in Java

Tags: java, recursion, data-structures

I've written a recursive method that should return a tree node which fits a specific course. The method works great but instead of returning the value it returns only null.
Any idea how to solve it? Here is the code:

```
private TrieNode<String,V> prefix_last_child(TrieNode<String,V> STN , String prefix) {
    if (prefix.equals("")) {
        return STN;
    }
    char[] prefix = prefix.toCharArray();
    if (STN.getNexts().get(alphabet_place(prefix[0])) == null) {
        return null;
    }
    if (!prefix.equals(""))
        prefix_last_child(STN.getNexts().get(alphabet_place(prefix[0])), prefix.substring(1));
    return null;
}
```

Comment: that's probably because of the return null; at the end of the function? Did you try to debug your program step by step for small inputs? like one node, two nodes and three nodes? I think you will get what you're doing wrong by that..

Comment: You can investigate such problems yourself by using a debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is very close to working correctly. Here is the problem:

```
if (!prefix.equals(""))
    // You make a recursive invocation, and then...
    prefix_last_child(STN.getNexts().get(alphabet_place(prefix[0])), prefix.substring(1));
// ...ignore its return value, and return null instead!
return null;
```

Replace with

```
if (!prefix.equals(""))
    return prefix_last_child(STN.getNexts().get(alphabet_place(prefix[0])), prefix.substring(1));
//  ^^^^^^
return null;
```

to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are only ever returning `null` or the constant `STN` from the function. There is no way a meaningful/non-fixed value can even be returned.

Comment: `STN` *is* a meaningful value that the OP is after.

Answer (score 0):

To write a recursive method, replace

```
 if (!prefix.equals(""))
        prefix_last_child(STN.getNexts().get(alphabet_place(prefix[0])), prefix.substring(1));
```

with

```
 if (!prefix.equals(""))
      return  prefix_last_child(STN.getNexts().get(alphabet_place(prefix[0])), prefix.substring(1));
```

Comment: When answering by code fragment please describe how it works and what it fixes.